# Clear text of a Html.TextBoxFor with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I can't seem to figure out how to clear the text from a razor Textbox.

I've tried this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field)


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".link").click(function () {                
            $("#Field").value = "";
            return false;
        });    
    });
```

Didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to SET the value with jQuery is to use `val` and pass it a value. So to clear it, use this:

```
$("#Field").val("")
```

Look at the jQuery API for `val`:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

If you wanted to use basic Javascript, you use `.value = ""`, but since you are selecting an element with jQuery, you must use jQuery methods, like `val`.

You have several options though. This is similarly very easy with basic Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("Field").value = "";
```

If you still wanted to use jQuery but use `value`, you need to get the DOM element, like:

```
$("#Field")[0].value = "";
// or
$("#Field").get(0).value = "";
```

If you are using jQuery, you might as well stick with `val()`. The nice thing with this is that calling `.val("")` will not bomb the program if the element isn't found. If you use any of the other methods I mentioned, they will bomb if the element doesn't exist. So it's up to you what you really want. You can always check to see if `$("#Field").length` is greater than 0 before using `get(0)` or `[0]`, but that's kind of overkill.

Another possible problem is that the `id` of the element may not be "Field". I forget what MVC does to generate the actual HTML, but it's up to you to use something like Firebug or Developer Tools to investigate and see what the `id` actually is. Then, you may have to replace it for "Field".

Comment: Although, if you're really itching to use vanilla JavaScript to set the value: `$("#Field").get(0).value = "";` -- but that's a little silly.

Comment: @andytuba Not sure if that comment came before or after one of my edits, but I do include that. But I definitely agree. It's really unnecessary to do that. It's either stick with all vanilla or all jQuery

Comment: I put it in just before your edit. I was entertained when I saw the notification that "This answer has been edited" and up popped the same code.